# Find element with style attribute and change it

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, html-table

First I don't know if I'm calling the objects the correct name.

But is it possible to loop through a html file and select an  tag with the style attribute bgcolor (I know this is outdated).

Every x amount of times I need the element  with the style attribute bgcolor. To have an other color than the other  elements. The x amount of times is irregular and not constant, there is no constant factor except for the bgcolor tag.

I've tried to figure out what element I can use that behaves consistantly in order to use that as starting point. The only one found is the bgcolor tag.

This is the code where I retrieve the html info from.

```php
<?php
    //get url var
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    if(empty($page)){
        $page = '2';
    }
$page2nav = '';

if($page=="2"){
    $output = file_get_contents('linktodata');
    $output = strip_tags($output,'<body><div><button><style><td><table><td.white><tr><tbody><b><script>');
    $page2nav = ' class="active"';
}
?>
```

```php
    <div class="contentwrapper">
      <div class="content">
        <?php echo $output; ?>
    </div>
    </div>
```

css that is pulled with the php script

```css
<style type="text/css">
    td.white{border-style: none;} 
    TD {font-family: Arial; 
        font-size: 11pt;
        max-width: 500px;
        word-wrap: break-word;} 
    body {color: black; background: white;} 
    table { border-collapse: collapse } 
    td { border: 1px solid black 
         max-width: 500px;
         word-wrap: break-word;}
    </style>
```

```html
<TABLE BORDER=1 id="table"><tbody><tr bgcolor="orange"><td colspan="9">blablablablablablablabla</td></tr><tr><b><td>datum</td><td align="center">M</td><td align="center">V</td><td>blabla</td><td>resource</td><td>blablag</td></tr><tr bgcolor="orange">                                 
<td> <b>22-04-2019</b> </td>                                
<td align="center"> <b>6</b> </td>                                
<td align="center"> <b>4</b> </td>                                
<td> <b>blabla</b> </td>                                
<td> <b> no caterteam </b> </td>                                
<td> <b>no kok </b> </td>                                
</tr>
<tr>                                
<td class="white"></td>                                
<td align="center" width="25">6</td>                                
<td align="center" width="25"></td>                                
<td>blabla</td>                                
<td>blabla</td>                                
<td>blabla</td>                                
</tr>
<tr>                             
<td class="white"></td>                             
<td align="center" width="25"></td>                             
<td align="center" width="25">4</td>                             
<td>blabla</td>                             
<td>PersoneelsCatering Veggie</td>                             
<td>avondcatering</td>                             
</tr><tr bgcolor="orange">                                 
<td> <b>23-04-2019</b> </td>                                
<td align="center"> <b>14</b> </td>                                
<td align="center"> <b>10</b> </td>                                
<td> <b>blabla</b> </td>                                
<td> <b>blala</b> </td>                                
<td> <b>blabla </b> </td>                                
</tr>
<tr>                                
<td class="white"></td>                                
<td align="center" width="25"></td>                                
<td align="center" width="25">4</td>                                
<td></td>                                
<td>blalal</td>                                
<td>blalal</td>                                
</tr>
<tr>                             
<td class="white"></td>                             
<td align="center" width="25">6</td>                             
<td align="center" width="25"></td>                             
<td>blabla</td>                             
<td>blabla</td>                             
<td>blabla</td>                             
</tr>
<tr>                             
<td class="white"></td>                             
<td align="center" width="25">1</td>                             
<td align="center" width="25"></td>                             
<td></td>                             
<td>blabla</td>                             
<td>blabla</td>                             
</tr>
```

The only repeating thing is the bgcolor:orange.

My plan is to change these rows with the orange color in an other color.

Comment: sure possible. but maybe explain what you want to achieve with it, because the solution you're proposing and need help with seems to be the wrong move already.

Comment: What determines the "x" amount? Do you want it to be random?

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of changing elements with bgcolor attribute. See if it fits you. If it doesn't explain better and I'll try to help you further.

```js
function changeBgColorElements(color) {
    var list = document.querySelectorAll('[bgcolor]');
    list.forEach(e=>e.setAttribute('bgcolor',color));  
}


changeBgColorElements('green');
```

```html
<TABLE BORDER=1 id="table"><tbody><tr bgcolor="orange"><td colspan="9">blablablablablablablabla</td></tr><tr><b><td>datum</td><td align="center">M</td><td align="center">V</td><td>blabla</td><td>resource</td><td>blablag</td></tr><tr bgcolor="orange">                                 
<td> <b>22-04-2019</b> </td>                                
<td align="center"> <b>6</b> </td>                                
<td align="center"> <b>4</b> </td>                                
<td> <b>blabla</b> </td>                                
<td> <b> no caterteam </b> </td>                                
<td> <b>no kok </b> </td>                                
</tr>
<tr>                                
<td class="white"></td>                                
<td align="center" width="25">6</td>                                
<td align="center" width="25"></td>                                
<td>blabla</td>                                
<td>blabla</td>                                
<td>blabla</td>                                
</tr>
<tr>                             
<td class="white"></td>                             
<td align="center" width="25"></td>                             
<td align="center" width="25">4</td>                             
<td>blabla</td>                             
<td>PersoneelsCatering Veggie</td>                             
<td>avondcatering</td>                             
</tr><tr bgcolor="orange">                                 
<td> <b>23-04-2019</b> </td>                                
<td align="center"> <b>14</b> </td>                                
<td align="center"> <b>10</b> </td>                                
<td> <b>blabla</b> </td>                                
<td> <b>blala</b> </td>                                
<td> <b>blabla </b> </td>                                
</tr>
<tr>                                
<td class="white"></td>                                
<td align="center" width="25"></td>                                
<td align="center" width="25">4</td>                                
<td></td>                                
<td>blalal</td>                                
<td>blalal</td>                                
</tr>
<tr>                             
<td class="white"></td>                             
<td align="center" width="25">6</td>                             
<td align="center" width="25"></td>                             
<td>blabla</td>                             
<td>blabla</td>                             
<td>blabla</td>                             
</tr>
<tr>                             
<td class="white"></td>                             
<td align="center" width="25">1</td>                             
<td align="center" width="25"></td>                             
<td></td>                             
<td>blabla</td>                             
<td>blabla</td>                             
</tr>
```